# Difficulty connecting to a database with Primavera P6

Tags: database, project-management, primavera

I'm having trouble connecting to Primavera P6 (project). When I enter my username and password, I receive an error:

```
This user is already logged in...
```

The password was never changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen. If you have access to the database try retrieving the records for your login via the USESSION and USERS table.

```
SELECT us.actual_name, dbo.USESSION.*  
FROM dbo.USERS AS us 
     LEFT JOIN dbo.USESSION ON us.user_id = dbo.USESSION.user_id 
WHERE user_name = 'your_login_name'
```

You might be able to reset the login with a delete on this session.

```
DELETE FROM dbo.USESSION where session_id = <your_session_id>
```

Otherwise call Primavera Support.

Comment: ok but i can't se the window to open the oracle command line either

Comment: I don't think there is a command line in the login window. You'd have to open up SQL/Plus on the Oracle database server (or ask your DBA) and then execute the scripts. Oracle might have a slightly different syntax. My statements refer to a database installation on Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: If running a client only installation on your desktop/laptop then you would find Oracle SQL/Plus in the Oracle Program Folder.